# Why is filling a pandas data frame so resource intensive

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have 1106 columns and 6689 rows to be filled in a sparse matrix that is filled by reading a csv file using DictReader from the csv library.
There are some bad columns so I want to remove those (currently trying to identify which ones are the bad columns).

Anyway here's the code:

```
def read_annotations(filehandle):
    with open(filehandle, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        workers = defaultdict(list)
        ids = []

        for row in reader:
            # CF annotators given a choice to choose link on their request, We treat it as neither (so do expert raters
            if row['which_form_of_hate_speech_is_this'].lower() == 'link':
                row['which_form_of_hate_speech_is_this'] = 'neither'

            # Create a dictionary containing each annotation by a worker, 
            # save their trust score, their annotation, the id of the tweet and the tweet in a tuple
            workers[row['_worker_id']].append((row['_trust'], row['which_form_of_hate_speech_is_this'], row['id'], row['tweet']))

    return workers, set(ids)

def annotation_writer(workers, ids):
    """ Writes a annotations to file where each column is a worker and each row is a tweet ID
    :param workers: Dictionary containing worker ID as key, trust, annotation, tweet id and tweet as tuple
    """

    # Create empty dataframe with tweet IDS as indexes and workers as columns
    df = pd.DataFrame(index = ids, columns= list(workers.keys()))

    # Go through each worker
    bad_annotators = [683, 691, 694, 691]
    for i, w_idx in enumerate(workers):
        # Go through each list item
        if i <= 693:
            if i in bad_annotators:
                print(w_idx)
                continue
            for item in workers[w_idx]:
                _, label, idx, tweet = item
                # Set the label they have chosen for the item at index: TweetID and row worker_id
                df.set_value(idx, w_idx, label)

    return df
```

The profiling output ordered by cumulative time:

```
        tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        466/1    0.020    0.000  361.865  361.865 {built-in method builtins.exec}
            1    0.000    0.000  361.865  361.865 annotator.py:1(<module>)
            1   93.955   93.955  360.789  360.789 annotator.py:24(annotation_writer)
        20923    0.143    0.000  266.759    0.013 frame.py:1840(set_value)
         6594    0.088    0.000  265.032    0.040 indexing.py:126(__setitem__)
         6594    0.478    0.000  263.543    0.040 indexing.py:224(_setitem_with_indexer)
         6594    0.077    0.000  254.250    0.039 frame.py:2743(reindex_axis)
         6594    0.071    0.000  254.173    0.039 generic.py:2307(reindex_axis)
         6594    0.144    0.000  250.682    0.038 generic.py:2320(_reindex_with_indexers)
         6594    0.095    0.000  250.327    0.038 internals.py:3560(reindex_indexer)
         6594    0.029    0.000  249.124    0.038 internals.py:3595(<listcomp>)
         6594    0.155    0.000  249.096    0.038 internals.py:975(take_nd)
         6594    0.239    0.000  248.633    0.038 algorithms.py:840(take_nd)
        34098  140.266    0.004  140.266    0.004 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
         6594  107.927    0.016  107.927    0.016 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_object_object}
        40942    0.136    0.000    4.503    0.000 base.py:1915(get_loc)
        54130    4.213    0.000    4.242    0.000 {method 'get_loc' of 'pandas.index.IndexEngine' objects}
         6594    0.052    0.000    3.299    0.001 base.py:2295(reindex)
         6594    0.079    0.000    3.099    0.000 base.py:2028(get_indexer)
         6594    2.871    0.000    2.923    0.000 {method 'get_indexer' of 'pandas.index.IndexEngine' objects}
         6594    0.075    0.000    2.321    0.000 base.py:3011(insert)
        13189    0.112    0.000    1.707    0.000 internals.py:2578(__init__)
  19787/13191    0.368    0.000    1.620    0.000 base.py:124(__new__)
         6594    0.027    0.000    1.519    0.000 internals.py:2916(setitem)
         6594    0.108    0.000    1.492    0.000 internals.py:2811(apply)
        20923    0.084    0.000    1.434    0.000 generic.py:1345(_get_item_cache)
         6594    0.034    0.000    1.359    0.000 indexing.py:101(_get_setitem_indexer)
         6594    0.048    0.000    1.281    0.000 indexing.py:163(_convert_tuple)
        13188    0.105    0.000    1.229    0.000 indexing.py:1102(_convert_to_indexer)
        13189    0.456    0.000    1.155    0.000 internals.py:2674(_rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs)
         6594    0.043    0.000    1.008    0.000 base.py:522(_coerce_scalar_to_index)
        13192    0.869    0.000    0.895    0.000 {pandas.lib.infer_dtype}
         6594    0.031    0.000    0.761    0.000 base.py:354(_shallow_copy_with_infer)
         6594    0.130    0.000    0.720    0.000 internals.py:628(setitem)
         7283    0.082    0.000    0.694    0.000 internals.py:3283(get)
        20473    0.167    0.000    0.669    0.000 internals.py:2482(make_block)
        13188    0.020    0.000    0.639    0.000 base.py:950(is_integer)
         6595    0.010    0.000    0.619    0.000 base.py:1172(inferred_type)
        571/2    0.004    0.000    0.610    0.305 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:966(_find_and_load)
        571/2    0.003    0.000    0.610    0.305 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:939(_find_and_load_unlocked)
        452/2    0.003    0.000    0.610    0.305 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:659(_load_unlocked)
        387/2    0.002    0.000    0.610    0.305 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:656(exec_module)
        599/2    0.001    0.000    0.609    0.305 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:214(_call_with_frames_removed)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.609    0.304 __init__.py:5(<module>)
989631/989629    0.370    0.000    0.603    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
         7283    0.047    0.000    0.593    0.000 frame.py:2331(_box_item_values)
         7283    0.031    0.000    0.480    0.000 frame.py:2338(_box_col_values)
            1    0.068    0.068    0.465    0.465 annotator.py:7(read_annotations)
        13877    0.069    0.000    0.463    0.000 internals.py:183(make_block_same_class)
         7283    0.038    0.000    0.449    0.000 series.py:236(from_array)
     432/41    0.001    0.000    0.440    0.011 {built-in method builtins.__import__}
         7283    0.133    0.000    0.438    0.000 internals.py:3312(iget)
        31512    0.141    0.000    0.389    0.000 csv.py:106(__next__)
        20472    0.176    0.000    0.381    0.000 internals.py:1657(__init__)
         7284    0.054    0.000    0.369    0.000 series.py:120(__init__)
70099/69243    0.051    0.000    0.367    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:996(_handle_fromlist)
         6594    0.350    0.000    0.350    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
        19787    0.116    0.000    0.329    0.000 common.py:1380(_asarray_tuplesafe)
         6594    0.032    0.000    0.310    0.000 internals.py:171(make_block)
533564/425149    0.221    0.000    0.290    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        32973    0.122    0.000    0.282    0.000 internals.py:2619(shape)
     232315    0.230    0.000    0.270    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
        41781    0.055    0.000    0.267    0.000 common.py:1710(is_datetimetz)
        54821    0.182    0.000    0.260    0.000 generic.py:2674(__setattr__)
        40673    0.061    0.000    0.251    0.000 numeric.py:414(asarray)
        58149    0.225    0.000    0.238    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
     126058    0.096    0.000    0.231    0.000 generic.py:7(_check)
     103351    0.124    0.000    0.230    0.000 dtypes.py:74(is_dtype)
        61570    0.068    0.000    0.227    0.000 common.py:1736(is_categorical_dtype)
278263/278240    0.222    0.000    0.223    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
        31532    0.214    0.000    0.222    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
        13188    0.043    0.000    0.220    0.000 indexing.py:183(_convert_scalar_indexer)
        15213    0.030    0.000    0.208    0.000 {method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        52752    0.059    0.000    0.206    0.000 generic.py:333(_get_axis)
         6595    0.054    0.000    0.201    0.000 internals.py:2799(_verify_integrity)
             27    0.001    0.000    0.195    0.007 __init__.py:1(<module>)
 20473    0.097    0.000    0.194    0.000 internals.py:77(__init__)
         6595    0.060    0.000    0.194    0.000 frame.py:210(__init__)
        19782    0.042    0.000    0.179    0.000 generic.py:2713(_protect_consolidate)
        15213    0.015    0.000    0.178    0.000 _methods.py:37(_any)
         6594    0.013    0.000    0.171    0.000 internals.py:555(_try_coerce_and_cast_result)
        13188    0.046    0.000    0.168    0.000 generic.py:1407(_maybe_update_cacher)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.167    0.167 api.py:5(<module>)
        13189    0.069    0.000    0.164    0.000 internals.py:3004(_consolidate_check)
        15213    0.163    0.000    0.163    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        98919    0.034    0.000    0.159    0.000 internals.py:2621(<genexpr>)
         7284    0.032    0.000    0.156    0.000 series.py:270(_set_axis)
         6594    0.029    0.000    0.156    0.000 internals.py:510(_try_cast_result)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.155    0.155 groupby.py:1(<module>)
        13188    0.023    0.000    0.150    0.000 generic.py:2723(_consolidate_inplace)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.145    0.145 frame.py:10(<module>)
         6594    0.047    0.000    0.141    0.000 common.py:527(_maybe_promote)
        15402    0.024    0.000    0.138    0.000 common.py:1731(is_categorical)
        13188    0.046    0.000    0.136    0.000 base.py:972(_convert_scalar_indexer)
        13191    0.073    0.000    0.131    0.000 base.py:309(_simple_new)
        59346    0.094    0.000    0.128    0.000 generic.py:320(_get_axis_name)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.126    0.126 __init__.py:106(<module>)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.125    0.063 __init__.py:9(<module>)
1514/1502    0.050    0.000    0.125    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
                2    0.000    0.000    0.123    0.062 __init__.py:15(<module>)
        54132    0.091    0.000    0.117    0.000 {pandas.lib.values_from_object}
         6595    0.029    0.000    0.115    0.000 base.py:1507(equals)
        41781    0.037    0.000    0.108    0.000 common.py:1575(is_datetime64tz_dtype)
         6595    0.033    0.000    0.106    0.000 base.py:1180(is_all_dates)
        52760    0.057    0.000    0.104    0.000 base.py:440(values)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.104    0.104 series.py:3(<module>)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.102    0.102 add_newdocs.py:10(<module>)
            387    0.004    0.000    0.102    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:726(get_code)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.100    0.100 config_init.py:11(<module>)
     107722    0.069    0.000    0.097    0.000 base.py:409(__len__)
        13188    0.038    0.000    0.095    0.000 generic.py:2726(f)
         6594    0.025    0.000    0.093    0.000 indexing.py:1860(maybe_convert_ix)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.093    0.093 plotting.py:3(<module>)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.090    0.090 converter.py:1(<module>)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.089    0.089 format.py:2(<module>)
        13189    0.022    0.000    0.089    0.000 internals.py:3005(<listcomp>)
        27482    0.087    0.000    0.087    0.000 {method 'fill' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
                1    0.000    0.000    0.087    0.087 type_check.py:3(<module>)
    6596    0.085    0.000    0.085    0.000 {built-in method pandas.lib.list_to_object_array}
    435/433    0.001    0.000    0.084    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:570(module_from_spec)
        20923    0.082    0.000    0.082    0.000 {method 'set_value' of 'pandas.index.IndexEngine' objects}
                1    0.002    0.002    0.075    0.075 frame.py:307(_init_dict)
        13190    0.075    0.000    0.075    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
         6594    0.024    0.000    0.075    0.000 internals.py:1665(is_bool)
         6594    0.057    0.000    0.074    0.000 algorithms.py:807(_get_take_nd_function)
        13188    0.054    0.000    0.073    0.000 base.py:506(_get_attributes_dict)
            764    0.002    0.000    0.072    0.000 re.py:278(_compile)
            192    0.000    0.000    0.071    0.000 re.py:222(compile)
        43/42    0.000    0.000    0.071    0.002 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:900(create_module)
        43/42    0.055    0.001    0.070    0.002 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
            167    0.001    0.000    0.070    0.000 sre_compile.py:531(compile)
            387    0.001    0.000    0.070    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:471(_compile_bytecode)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.068    0.068 __init__.py:101(<module>)
            387    0.067    0.000    0.067    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
        13188    0.028    0.000    0.067    0.000 common.py:1532(is_dtype_equal)
        13189    0.060    0.000    0.066    0.000 internals.py:276(ftype)
    540/539    0.006    0.000    0.066    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:879(_find_spec)
        20472    0.065    0.000    0.065    0.000 generic.py:2658(__getattr__)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.064    0.064 frame.py:5224(_arrays_to_mgr)
         6594    0.011    0.000    0.064    0.000 generic.py:2753(_is_mixed_type)
        13189    0.038    0.000    0.063    0.000 internals.py:2579(<listcomp>)
        13879    0.062    0.000    0.062    0.000 generic.py:94(__init__)
        13191    0.019    0.000    0.057    0.000 common.py:1696(is_bool_dtype)
         7283    0.009    0.000    0.057    0.000 common.py:73(isnull)
        20923    0.017    0.000    0.057    0.000 series.py:366(_values)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.056    0.028 common.py:1(<module>)
            535    0.001    0.000    0.055    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1130(find_spec)
         7284    0.036    0.000    0.055    0.000 internals.py:3778(__init__)
            535    0.004    0.000    0.055    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1098(_get_spec)
        53448    0.044    0.000    0.054    0.000 base.py:3381(_ensure_index)
        20473    0.046    0.000    0.054    0.000 internals.py:191(mgr_locs)
        59355    0.053    0.000    0.053    0.000 {method 'view' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
         6594    0.036    0.000    0.052    0.000 common.py:733(_possibly_downcast_to_dtype)
            990    0.011    0.000    0.052    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1212(find_spec)
         6594    0.013    0.000    0.051    0.000 generic.py:1476(_check_is_chained_assignment_possible)
                2    0.001    0.000    0.051    0.026 pyparsing.py:58(<module>)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.051    0.051 rcsetup.py:15(<module>)
         7283    0.022    0.000    0.049    0.000 generic.py:1359(_set_as_cached)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.048    0.048 fontconfig_pattern.py:7(<module>)
        26380    0.036    0.000    0.048    0.000 common.py:1511(_get_dtype_type)
         7283    0.033    0.000    0.048    0.000 common.py:94(_isnull_new)
         6594    0.029    0.000    0.048    0.000 base.py:2201(_possibly_promote)
         7284    0.020    0.000    0.045    0.000 series.py:302(name)
                1    0.002    0.002    0.045    0.045 frame.py:5521(_homogenize)
        95791    0.044    0.000    0.044    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        19783    0.017    0.000    0.043    0.000 base.py:870(_values)
        13188    0.014    0.000    0.043    0.000 indexing.py:1890(is_list_like_indexer)
         1105    0.003    0.000    0.043    0.000 series.py:2787(_sanitize_array)
         6594    0.042    0.000    0.042    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_bool_array}
169/167    0.001    0.000    0.042    0.000 sre_parse.py:819(parse)
        26377    0.027    0.000    0.041    0.000 internals.py:3276(_consolidate_inplace)
         6595    0.041    0.000    0.041    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_datetime_array}
        19782    0.027    0.000    0.041    0.000 indexing.py:128(<genexpr>)
        20923    0.026    0.000    0.040    0.000 internals.py:3911(internal_values)
194369/194289    0.038    0.000    0.040    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
    557/169    0.003    0.000    0.040    0.000 sre_parse.py:429(_parse_sub)
    751/186    0.014    0.000    0.039    0.000 sre_parse.py:491(_parse)
        26376    0.031    0.000    0.039    0.000 common.py:1491(_get_dtype)
         6594    0.013    0.000    0.038    0.000 generic.py:1402(_is_view)
                6    0.000    0.000    0.038    0.006 api.py:3(<module>)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.038    0.038 __init__.py:27(<module>)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.037    0.019 __init__.py:7(<module>)
         1105    0.002    0.000    0.037    0.000 series.py:2804(_try_cast)
         6595    0.019    0.000    0.037    0.000 common.py:272(array_equivalent)
         6594    0.010    0.000    0.036    0.000 generic.py:2755(<lambda>)
        13207    0.025    0.000    0.036    0.000 __init__.py:168(iteritems)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.036    0.018 __init__.py:26(<module>)
         6596    0.024    0.000    0.036    0.000 base.py:1143(_engine)
         6594    0.014    0.000    0.035    0.000 generic.py:337(_get_block_manager_axis)
         7284    0.022    0.000    0.033    0.000 series.py:306(name)
        34350    0.032    0.000    0.032    0.000 {pandas.lib.isscalar}
         6877    0.006    0.000    0.032    0.000 {built-in method builtins.all}
        14294    0.022    0.000    0.031    0.000 common.py:1763(is_list_like)
        13188    0.021    0.000    0.030    0.000 indexing.py:547(<genexpr>)
        53445    0.030    0.000    0.030    0.000 internals.py:160(mgr_locs)
         6596    0.010    0.000    0.030    0.000 base.py:1146(<lambda>)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.029    0.014 __init__.py:2912(_call_aside)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.029    0.029 __init__.py:2927(_initialize_master_working_set)
         7283    0.026    0.000    0.028    0.000 base.py:1247(__getitem__)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.028    0.028 generic.py:2(<module>)
         6608    0.028    0.000    0.028    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
        13188    0.019    0.000    0.028    0.000 generic.py:1441(_clear_item_cache)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.027    0.027 requirements.py:4(<module>)
        13190    0.009    0.000    0.026    0.000 base.py:445(get_values)
            167    0.000    0.000    0.026    0.000 sre_compile.py:516(_code)
         6594    0.012    0.000    0.026    0.000 internals.py:3009(is_mixed_type)
        21161    0.026    0.000    0.026    0.000 internals.py:2695(_get_items)
         6595    0.011    0.000    0.025    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
         6594    0.015    0.000    0.025    0.000 internals.py:3027(is_view)
        13188    0.015    0.000    0.025    0.000 internals.py:3260(consolidate)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.024    0.012 __init__.py:45(<module>)
        39565    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 internals.py:2996(is_consolidated)
            523    0.001    0.000    0.024    0.000 decorators.py:181(__call__)
         7283    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 internals.py:301(iget)
            545    0.004    0.000    0.023    0.000 textwrap.py:415(dedent)
         6594    0.021    0.000    0.023    0.000 common.py:446(_infer_dtype_from_scalar)
                2    0.000    0.000    0.023    0.011 index.py:2(<module>)
         6594    0.020    0.000    0.022    0.000 generic.py:124(_init_mgr)
        63023    0.022    0.000    0.022    0.000 csv.py:92(fieldnames)
         6594    0.017    0.000    0.021    0.000 generic.py:307(_get_axis_number)
             23    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.001 pyparsing.py:798(_trim_arity)
             22    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.001 pyparsing.py:806(extract_stack)
             22    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.001 traceback.py:192(extract_stack)
             22    0.004    0.000    0.021    0.001 traceback.py:303(extract)
             30    0.001    0.000    0.021    0.001 __init__.py:349(namedtuple)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.021 internals.py:1(<module>)
         6594    0.012    0.000    0.020    0.000 common.py:1550(is_integer_dtype)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.020    0.020 parser.py:5(<module>)
        13188    0.016    0.000    0.020    0.000 base.py:508(<listcomp>)
 1320/167    0.006    0.000    0.019    0.000 sre_compile.py:64(_compile)
             19    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.001 pyparsing.py:958(setParseAction)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.019 feedparser.py:20(<module>)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.019 internals.py:3996(create_block_manager_from_arrays)
        19784    0.015    0.000    0.019    0.000 internals.py:2623(ndim)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.019 dates.py:111(<module>)
                1    0.003    0.003    0.019    0.019 internals.py:4007(form_blocks)
        13188    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 internals.py:650(<lambda>)
        13198    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 dtypes.py:122(construct_from_string)
         7284    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 series.py:292(_set_subtyp)
        13188    0.012    0.000    0.018    0.000 missing.py:559(clean_reindex_fill_method)
         1105    0.005    0.000    0.018    0.000 common.py:1011(_possibly_cast_to_datetime)
        88922    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
         3288    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 {built-in method posix.stat}
         6594    0.005    0.000    0.017    0.000 base.py:3425(_ensure_has_len)
         6594    0.012    0.000    0.017    0.000 internals.py:4301(_extend_blocks)
        17/16    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:630(_load_backward_compatible)
                5    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.003 __init__.py:34(load_module)
                1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 message.py:5(<module>)
         2634    0.002    0.000    0.016    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:68(_path_stat)
             14    0.000    0.000    0.016    0.001 __init__.py:663(add_entry)
```

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question: I encountered this as well and created a list, appended to that list, then created a dataframe from the list.

Comment: And appending to a list is amortised O(1)...

Comment: Iterative assignment (or access) to an numpy array, and by extension a pandas dataframe is slow.  It's best to use operations that work on the whole array or frame at once, since that performs the iterations in faster compiled code.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay, fair enough, but then can you explain why there might have been a slowdown? Prior to this running slowly, it was running quite fast (less than a second). With the only changes in the code being enumerating and adding the conditional clause. Removing them didn't help either (though I'm not sure why it would, but desperate times you know).

Comment: I don't use `pandas` enough to have a clear idea.   But I wonder if at some point it switches from a structured array format (one dtype for all values in a column or series) to an `object` dtype.  Some posters observe a switch to objects when it has to introduce `nan` or `None` values in a column.  `pandas` introduces a whole new layer of complexity on top of `numpy`.